# Google sheets, adding rows, protecting rows simpler ways?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that is essentially a calendar/schedule, with January 1-31 grouped under January, February 1-28 under February, etc. and then under each day there will be rows for data input that will be grouped under that day.

Is there an easier way to go through and group everything other than going down individually adding a row and then grouping?
Second question there is no input needed on Sundays so that row will need to be blank/protected from editing so that users do not mess up the sheet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Bp0.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a column of consecutive dates with rows between,
you could use the following column to generate and copy and paste as text:

```
=ArrayFormula(FLATTEN({DATE(2021,1,1)+SEQUENCE(100,1,0,1),IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A100),2,,)/0,)}))
```

If you want to group the dates by months, and group the rows by days similar to you screenshot.

You would need a Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you, now my next issue is I am trying to make a data dependent dropdown.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Please create a new question for that.